# PHP MVC .htaccess - best practice to get URL parameters and hide index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I am making PHP MVC on my own. I read lot of info on the Internet for .htaccess but still it's very complicated for me. I have index.php in my public folder, which is the entry point for the app. Here's my directory structure:

- App

  - controllers
  - models
  - ...
  - **public**

    - js
    - img
    - **index.php <= entry point**
    - .htacccess
- Framework

  - Routers
  - Session
  - FrontController
  - ...

So in the public folder I have only index.php and .htaccess file. What I want to do is:

1. Each request to point to index.php
2. When the user enters `http://localhost/myApp/` to load url like `http://localhost/myApp` (without a slash in the end)
3. I want to disable using `index.php` in the url (except for home page). To make it clear, here's an example:
   If user enters `http://localhost/myApp/index.php`, the url is fine. But when he enters `http://localhost/myApp/index.php/user/Chris`, I want an error page to show up. Instead, I only want this `http://localhost/myApp/user/Chris` to work.

I also would like to know what is the correct way to access controller, model, parameters from URL. I know that `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` always exist, but I can't rely on `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` because they might no exist, right? I use `substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) + 1);` to get erything after `http://localhost/myApp`.

This is the .htaccess I wrote so far
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

This code seems to do some of the things I want, but it's not enough. When I enter `http://localhost/myApp/index.php/user` it still works, instead of giving error.

By the way, what is the best way to show 404 not found page? using htaccess, or using php? Also, what happens from SEO point when you have millions of 404 not found pages in your site? How to handle that? Can you get penalized for having so much pages with same content?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the 404 part: You can use whatever you'd like, as long as you return a 404 Response Code in your HTTP header (for example, using `http_response_code(404);` in PHP). Google is not penalizing 404s. Source: https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/RMjFPCSs5fm

Comment: @TiborB. what about canonical urls?

Answer (score 0):

I've made my own MVC framework too.
It's in three parts :

- prevent direct acces to index.php
- prevent rewrite for existing files (useful for image/css/js/font files)
- proper url rewrite

In my case, I choose to parse the URL in PHP instead of the .htaccess.
So all the URL is put in $_GET['uri'] and other get data are append by Apache after (QSA flag)

Here the code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php - [END,R=404]    #prevent direct access

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] #if file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d      #or directory exists
RewriteRule . - [END,QSA]               #do nothing

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?uri=$1 [END,QSA] #all without the ending slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [END,QSA]  #all (no ending slash)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but believe it deserves a more detailed answer. The process is explained in the code comments.

```
RewriteEngine On

# If you decide to run your app from the domain root, then strip out "myApp/"

RewriteBase /myApp/

# First, trim all trailing slashes.

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Next, prevent access to URIs starting with index.php.
# Note: I generally recommend that you leave this out and let
#       your app handle redirects from index.php.

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php(?:.*) HTTP/1.1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

# Lastly, pipe requests that do not match existing files to index.php.
# This can be done in several ways, including the one you tried.
# Uncomment the one the works best for you.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In terms of accessing the requested URI, the last rule is the easiest to work with, and generally the most reliable. I prefer to make use of the first one, and use `REQUEST_URI`. The same can be done with the second. Using it is quite reliable - I don't know of any server that does not provide `REQUEST_URI` to the `$_SERVER` global. However, if that were to be the case, the third option would be best.

Regarding 404s, it's always better to allow your app to handle them. This gives you all the flexibility you need, especially when it comes to, say, providing suggestions based on the non-existing request. Google will not penalise you for the existence of many 404s, so long as they send the correct header. However, if Google is picking up most of your 404s from indexing your actual app/site, then it more than likely will. As such, your app should be *clever* and make sure Google is redirected to the correct page. This makes your the app/site layout very clear to Google, and it can understand what's going on.